# не срабатывает onNavigationItemSelected

Tags: java, android

> PhotoActivity:

```
package com.example.zaki.mycamera;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;

import com.example.zaki.mycamera.FileWork.FileWork;
import com.example.zaki.mycamera.SQLite.WorkSQLite;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import static com.example.zaki.mycamera.TimeWork.DateTime.getTime;

public class PhotoActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    SurfaceView surfaceView;
    Camera camera = null;
    MediaRecorder mediaRecorder;

    File pictures;

    Boolean cameraEnabled = false;

    private void getImageSurface() {
        surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);

        SurfaceHolder holder = surfaceView.getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                try {
                    camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
                    camera.startPreview();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format,
                                       int width, int height) {
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_photo);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        /*FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Hey", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });*/

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();


        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        //navigationView.setClickable(true);
        //navigationView.setContextClickable(true);

        pictures = Environment
                .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] { Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE }, 0);
        }
        else {
            cameraEnabled = true;
        }

        getImageSurface();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == 0) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                cameraEnabled = true;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (cameraEnabled) {
            camera = Camera.open();
        }
        getImageSurface();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if (cameraEnabled) {
            releaseMediaRecorder();
            if (camera != null)
                camera.stopPreview();
            camera.release();
            camera = null;
        }
        surfaceView = null;
    }

    private void releaseMediaRecorder() {
        if (mediaRecorder != null) {
            mediaRecorder.reset();
            mediaRecorder.release();
            mediaRecorder = null;
            camera.lock();
        }
    }

    public void onClickTakePhoto(View view) {
        if (cameraEnabled) {
            camera.takePicture(null, null, new PictureCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                    try {
                        String fileName = getTime().replaceAll(" ", "") + ".JPG";

                        File file = new File(pictures.getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+fileName);
                        if (!file.exists()) file.createNewFile();
                        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        fos.write(data);
                        fos.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            surfaceView = null;
            getImageSurface();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.delete) {
            FileWork.deleteFiles(WorkSQLite.GetPoints(this));
            return true;
        } else if (id == R.id.upload) {

            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();



        if (id == R.id.PhotoCamera) {
            //android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            //fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new ).commit();
            Intent photo = new Intent(this, PhotoActivity.class);
            startActivity(photo);
        } else if (id == R.id.VideoCamera) {
            Intent video = new Intent(this, VideoActivity.class);
            startActivity(video);
        } else if (id == R.id.MyPhotos) {
            Intent myPhotos = new Intent(this, FileActivity.class);
            myPhotos.putExtra("dir", "pic");
            startActivity(myPhotos);
        } else if (id == R.id.MyVideos) {
            Intent myVideos = new Intent(this, FileActivity.class);
            myVideos.putExtra("dir", "vid");
            startActivity(myVideos);
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

}
```

> activity_photo.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

    <include layout="@layout/photo"></include>
    <include layout="@layout/app_bar_main"></include>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

> photo.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surfaceView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="391dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp">
    </SurfaceView>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnTakePicture"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/surfaceView"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:onClick="onClickTakePhoto"
        android:text="@string/take_picture"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">
    </Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

> app_bar_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <!--tools:context="com.example.zaki.mycamera.PhotoActivity"-->

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

> nav_header_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@drawable/camera_pic"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:text="MyCamera"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="It's works (maybe)"
        android:textColorHighlight="@color/colorPrimary" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Что именно не срабатывает? Вы собираетесь делать боковое меню с переходами? Во всех активностях тоже это меню? Не подумали о том, что меню сначала должно закрываться, а потом меняться экран? Зачем вы ищете `DrawerLayout` повторно? Вы это делаете в `onCreate`. **Все же если вы хотите сделать боковое меню во всех активностях и плавные переходы,  то лучше использовать библиотеку `Material Drawer`**

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что `NavigationView` скоро станет `deprecated`. Его никто не использует! Вот уже какой раз замечаю - все либу юзают